# Как упростить код PHP?

Tags: php, инспекция-кода

```
function display_soc()
{
    function push_array($array, $name, $class){
        $arr = array(
            'n' => $name,
            'c' => $class
        );
        array_push($array, $arr);
        return $array;
    }

    $soc = array();
    ($vk = get_field('vk_link', 'option'))? $soc = push_array($soc, $vk, 'vk__icon') : '';
    ($fb = get_field('fb_link', 'option')) ? $soc = push_array($soc, $fb, 'fb__icon') : '';
    ($ig = get_field('ig_link', 'option')) ? $soc = push_array($soc, $ig, 'insta__icon') : '';
    ($viber = get_field('viber', 'option')) ? $soc =  push_array($soc, $viber, 'viber__icon') : '';
    ($whatsapp = get_field('whatsapp', 'option')) ? $soc = push_array($soc, $whatsapp, 'wapp__icon') : '';
    ($telegram = get_field('telegram', 'option')) ? $soc = push_array($soc, $telegram, 'telegram__icon') : '';

    $result = '';
    if ($soc) {
        foreach ($soc as $item) {
            $result .= '<a href="' . $item['n'] . '" class="' . $item['c'] . '" target="_blank"></a>' . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Сдается, что есть более простой способ вывода. Спасибо

Comment: А вы как-то пробовали упростить или интуитивно чувствуете, что можно упростить? И для чего упрощать?

Comment: У меня был еще длиннее код. Интуитивно чуствую, что всегда можно упростить, поэтому интересно обращаться к экспертам сюда.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как минимум, вот это:

```
($vk = get_field('vk_link', 'option'))? $soc = push_array($soc, $vk, 'vk__icon') : '';
($fb = get_field('fb_link', 'option')) ? $soc = push_array($soc, $fb, 'fb__icon') : '';
($ig = get_field('ig_link', 'option')) ? $soc = push_array($soc, $ig, 'insta__icon') : '';
($viber = get_field('viber', 'option')) ? $soc =  push_array($soc, $viber, 'viber__icon') : '';
($whatsapp = get_field('whatsapp', 'option')) ? $soc = push_array($soc, $whatsapp, 'wapp__icon') : '';
($telegram = get_field('telegram', 'option')) ? $soc = push_array($soc, $telegram, 'telegram__icon') : '';
```

можно записать как:

```
          // array('vk', 'fb', 'insta', 'viber', 'wapp', 'telegram');
$soc_icons = ['vk', 'fb', 'insta', 'viber', 'wapp', 'telegram']; 

foreach ($soc_icons as $icon) {
    $link = $icon.'_link';
    if ($net_name = get_field($link, 'option'))
        $soc = push_array($soc, $net_name, $icon.'__icon');        
}
```

чтоб втыкать вообще любые сети, если их количество будет расти.

---

А еще я не понял зачем в данном случае посредник в виде массива, если возвращаете все равно чисто ссылки.. поэтому вот это:

```
if ($soc) {        
    foreach ($soc as $key => $item) {
        $result .= '<a href="' . $item['n'] . '" class="' . $item['c'] . '" target="_blank">item№'.$key.'</a>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

мне кажется можно опустить и писать сразу:

```
$soc_icons = ['vk', 'fb', 'insta', 'viber', 'wapp', 'telegram'];

$result = '';
foreach ($soc_icons as $icon) {
    $link = $icon.'_link';
    if ($net_name = get_field($link, 'option'))            
        $result .= '<a href="' . $net_name . '" class="' . $icon.'__icon' . '" target="_blank"></a>' . PHP_EOL;
}

return $result;
```

А вот если вы делаете по-умному и хотите разделить логику от представления, то тогда вам надо будет возвращать из функции массив `$soc`.  А уже где-то в представлении делать цикл по данному массиву с формированием ссылок..

---

Итог у меня получился как-то так (не разделенный на логику и представление):

```
$soc_icons = ['vk', 'fb', 'insta', 'viber', 'wapp', 'telegram'];

function display_soc($icons_arr) {
    // не знаю что это за функция get_field и что она у вас делает
    // у меня она будет такая тупая))
    function get_field($link, $option) {
        return $link;
    }

    $result = '';
    foreach ($icons_arr as $icon) {
        $link = $icon.'_link';
        if ($net_name = get_field($link, 'option'))            
            $result .= '<a href="' . $net_name . '" class="' . $icon.'__icon' . '" target="_blank"></a>' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    return $result;
}

print_r(display_soc($soc_icons));
```

Comment: Просто белиссимо!

Comment: Если интресно,то гет филд, получение кастомнго поля в ворпресс

Comment: @RomualdShmidtelson не, не интересно))

Comment: Все равно, спасибо! =)